# htaccess redirecting www to non www is relentlessly bringing cached copy from google?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a non www setup for a domain **X.com.bd** . when typed **www.X.com.bd** it gives a **net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED** error and brings cached copy  suggestion page from google. I've written an .htaccess rule as

```
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$  http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

And here is my whole .htaccess snippet :

```
  <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   # Turn on URL rewriting
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /

   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

   # Protect application and system files from being viewed when the index.php is missing
   RewriteCond $1 ^(application|system|private|logs)

   # Rewrite to index.php/access_denied/URL
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/access_denied/$1 [PT,L]

   # Allow these directories and files to be displayed directly:
   RewriteCond $1  ^(index\.php|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico|public|assets|resources|css|js|images|_assets|img)

  # No rewriting
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [PT,L]

  # Rewrite to index.php/URL
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [PT,L] 

  </IfModule>
```

Now all I need is to redirect www.X.com.bd to X.com.bd

Any help is appreciated and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a htaccess problem (it's not even apache related).`net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED` means that there is no DNS resolution possible for www.X.com.bd. You will need to add www.X.com.bd to the DNS zone of x.com.bd.
Your domain registrar/webhost will most likely have a control panel where you can do this. Otherwise their support staff should be able to help you with this.

You should add a CNAME or A record (and/or AAAA if your server uses IPv6), like:

```
www.X.com.bd. IN CNAME X.com.bd
```

Or:

```
www.X.com.bd. IN A 127.0.0.1 // But then with your actual server's IPv4 address
www.X.com.bd. IN AAAA ::1 // Replace with your server's IPv6 address
```

Comment: Instead of going to the resolution problem cant I just rewrite the url so that it's okay to show www.x.com.bd but behind the scene it remaps to x.com.bd ?

Comment: You need to add a "CNAME" entry in your DNS zone configuration, from www.yourdomain.com to yourdomain.com.

Comment: No, the browser on the client-side needs to able to connect to www.X.com.bd at all, which it can't right now.

Comment: @Oldskool Does that mean both the www.X.com.bd and X.com.bd has to be valid domain names ?

Comment: @edam Yes it does, but it's quite a simple procedure. There's just an "alias" needed in the DNS zone to make sure the www version resolves to the proper IP address as well.

Comment: @Oldskool Where do I add the CNAME as www.X.com.bd. IN CNAME X.com.bd ?

Comment: @edam In the DNS zone for the domain. When in doubt, contact the party that registered X.com.bd for you. They should be able to help.

Comment: @Oldskool I'm in trouble then. I'm using AWS Route53 for domain. Can u help me in that ?

Comment: @Oldskool Okay I think I've found what I was looking for. But Will it be the same IP address as value and should I check the Aliases to Yes ?

Comment: @Oldskool I have added the CNAME but the  net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED is still there !